# How to make appended plots continous in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below python code to append the plots from different subplots into one [sixth] subplot. There is break between the consecutive plots in the sixth subplot (the line is not continuous). How do you eliminate the break between these consecutive plots and make them continuous?

Could anyone help me in this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=np.linspace(0,20,1000);
x2=np.linspace(20,40,1000);
x3=np.linspace(40,60,1000);
x4=np.linspace(60,80,1000);
x5=np.linspace(80,100,1000);

y1=(np.sin(3*x1)**3);
y2=np.cos(1*x2);
y3=np.sin(2*x3)**(2);
y4=np.cos(2*x4)**(3);
y5=np.sin(x5)*np.cos(x5);

plt.subplot(6,1,1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.grid() 

plt.subplot(6,1,2)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.grid() 

plt.subplot(6,1,3)
plt.plot(x3,y3)
plt.grid() 

plt.subplot(6,1,4)
plt.plot(x4,y4)
plt.grid() 

plt.subplot(6,1,5)
plt.plot(x5,y5)
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(6,1,6)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.plot(x3,y3)
plt.plot(x4,y4)
plt.plot(x5,y5)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of uploading a figure showing your plot. What do you mean by make the plots in the sixth subplot continuous? So that, for example, the green and red lines at x=40 connect? If so, what colour should the connection be?

Comment: What did you mean 'break'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plot one line with the data appended.

```
plt.subplot(6,1,6)
x6 = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))
y6 = np.concatenate((y1, y2, y3, y4, y5))
plt.plot(x6, y6) instead of calling 5 times
```

Now you are just plotting one continuous line.

Comment: This is what I was exactly looking for.You understood the exact requirement to make the output plot continuous.